# File templates in Qt Creator

Tags: eclipse-cdt, qt-creator

Salutations.  Currently, I use Eclipse (Galileo) with CDT and Boost libraries in OS X 10.5.  I have begun the adventure of learning Qt, and I have installed the free version of the Qt SDK.  I have grown quite accustomed to Eclipse, but unfortunately, integration has not been developed for Eclipse in OS X yet.

My question, therefore, is whether I can set Qt Creator to load template files for my header and source files (e.g., Doxygen comments in the headers and C++ comments in the source files).  In Eclipse, I can accomplish this in the Preferences > C/C++ > Code Styles > Code templates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Qt Creator, you can add a header (i.e. for licenses and copyright notices) in Options (Preferences on OS X) -> C++ -> License Template. You can also modify certain Qt specific aspects of the project, like how to integrated UI files ( Options -> Designer). More sophiscticated settings are requested (see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-126), but not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you because Qt Creator 1.3 touted the idea, but whenever I load the preferences, I do not see License Template available.  I have downloaded Qt Creator at various times and even attempted to compile it from source code, but I still have not found this option. I might be overlooking the option (perhaps in a different menu location), but I certainly have not found it where you suggested.

EDIT
I may have found the option.  I assumed it was a separate subsection under C++, but it is actually a line edit box accepting a filename.  Thanks for your help.